# Scraping all closed captions (subtitles) of a YouTube's creator's video library

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium, youtube

A script that scrapes all YouTube's videos closed captions(subtitles) of a single creator's video library. It scrapes either auto-generated or manually written subtitles. The script accepts a link to the creators video library, such as, "https://www.youtube.com/user/creator/videos" and outputs subtitles of each video to it own respective '.txt' file. I use Selenium to trigger the events and BeautifulSoup to scrape the content.

---

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re
import sys

# Clicks on "Load More" button to display all users videos. 
def display_all_videos(driver):
    while(True):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "yt-uix-load-more")))
            element.click()
        except:
            break

# Creates a list of tuples (video_title, video_link) of all 
# videos displayed on page 
def video_list(driver):
    videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yt-uix-tile-link")
    video_links = []
    for vid in videos:
        video_links.append((vid.text,vid.get_attribute("href")))
    return video_links

# Clicks on CC(Closed Caption) button in YouTube video
def enable_subtitles(driver):
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ytp-subtitles-button")))
    elem.click()

def subtitles_link(driver):
    time.sleep(1)
    timings = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries();")

    # Find string in timings that contains the substring 'srv3'
    # which is the subtitles link.
    link = ""
    for t in timings:
         for v in t.values():
             if "srv3" in str(v):
                 link = v
    return link

def create_file(title, link,subtitles):
    # remove illegal chars for file name
    title = "".join([c for c in filename if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c==' ']).rstrip()

    try:
        file = open(title + '.txt', 'w')    
        file.write('LINK: ' + link + '\n')
        file.write(subtitles)
        file.close()
    except:
        print("Can't create file for: " + title + " : " + link)

def scrape_subtitles(subtitle_link):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(subtitle_link).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

    # Remove tags (<*>), \n, and unecessary whitespace 
    s = re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', soup.prettify())   
    s = re.sub(r'\n', '', s)                    
    s = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', s ).strip()         
    return s

def main(argv):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

    # Visit page and load all videos to create a list of
    # tuples(video_name,video_link) of the videos 
    driver.get(argv[1])
    display_all_videos(driver)
    videos = video_list(driver)

    # Visit video's page and enable 'CC' to scrape the subtitles and 
    # save subtitles to '.txt' file. 
    for v in videos:
        driver.get(v[1])
        try:
            enable_subtitles(driver)
            link = subtitles_link(driver)
            subtitles = scrape_subtitles(link)
        except:
            subtitles = "No Closed Caption"
        create_file(v[0],v[1],subtitles)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

---

- Readable?
- Follows Python's best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Bug

This was probably a posting or a copy/paste bug - in `create_file()` you meant to name the first parameter to be `filename` instead of `title`.

#### Code Style and PEP8 notes

- use *more descriptive variable names* - `r`, `s`, `c`, `v` are not good variable names
- remove unused `TimeoutException` import, organize imports in groups and alphabetically ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))
- move the comments before the functions into proper *docstrings*
- [avoid catching broad exceptions via bare `except`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/771848)
- follow [PEP8 whitespace and newline usage guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) - specifically, whitespaces around the operators, two newlines between the function definitions

#### Third-party Library Usage notes

- `BeautifulSoup` constructor accepts a file-like object as well - you don't have to explicitly call `.read()` method
- it is a good idea to specify `BeautifulSoup`'s parser explicitly:

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")  # or "html5lib", or "lxml"
  ```

  Otherwise, `BeautifulSoup` would pick a parser automatically depending on what is available. This would mean that on your machine it may pick, say, `lxml` - on someone else's - `html5lib`, on other's `html.parser`. And, there might be different results since [different parser behave differently](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).
- a bigger problem is that you are not actually using `BeautifulSoup` capabilities at all - you are post-processing the "soup" with regular expressions. It looks like you can achieve the same by calling the `.get_text()` method on the "soup" object
- for better reusability I would probably assume `chromedriver` is in `PATH` instead of hardcoding the path to it explicitly
- you can reuse `WebDriverWait` instance instead of re-instantiating it multiple times
- you *never close the driver instance*
- `time.sleep()` is generally unreliable when used for waiting for something with `selenium` - recheck if you actually need it

#### Code Organization notes

You are passing `driver` to multiple methods - it may be a good idea to have a class with a `driver` and `wait` attributes for better reusability.

#### Some Syntax Sugar

- you can construct a list of videos with a list comprehension:

  ```
  [(video.text, video.get_attribute("href"))
   for video in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yt-uix-tile-link")]
  ```
- you can unpack the list of videos into filename and a link:

  ```
  for filename, link in videos:
  ```

#### Modified Code:

```
import sys
import time
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class YoutubeSubtitlesScraper:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

        self.driver.get(start_url)
        self.display_all_videos()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.driver.close()

    def display_all_videos(self):
        """Clicks on "Load More" button to display all users videos."""
        while True:
            try:
                element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "yt-uix-load-more")))
                element.click()
            except TimeoutException:
                break

    def subtitles(self):
        """Visits video's page, enables 'CC' to scrape the subtitles and generates filename, link and the subtitles content."""
        videos = [(video.text, video.get_attribute("href"))
                  for video in self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yt-uix-tile-link")]

        for filename, link in videos:
            self.driver.get(link)
            self.enable_subtitles()

            link = self.get_subtitles_link()
            yield filename, link, self.scrape_subtitles(link) if link else "No Closed Caption"

    def enable_subtitles(self):
        """Clicks on CC(Closed Caption) button in YouTube video."""
        show_subtitles_button = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ytp-subtitles-button")))
        show_subtitles_button.click()

    def get_subtitles_link(self):
        """Finds string in performance timings that contains the substring 'srv3' which is the subtitles link."""
        time.sleep(1)
        timings = self.driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries();")

        for timing in timings:
            for value in timing.values():
                if "srv3" in str(value):
                    return value
        return ""

    def scrape_subtitles(self, subtitle_link):
        """HTML parses subtitles."""
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(subtitle_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
        return soup.get_text(strip=True)


def create_file(filename, link, subtitles):
    """Creates file for the subtitle."""
    title = "".join([c for c in filename if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c == ' ']).rstrip()

    with open(title + '.txt', 'w') as subtitles_file:
        subtitles_file.write('LINK: ' + link + '\n')
        subtitles_file.write(subtitles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_url = sys.argv[1]

    with YoutubeSubtitlesScraper(start_url) as scraper:
        for filename, link, content in scraper.subtitles():
            try:
                create_file(filename, link, content)
            except:
                print("Can't create file for: " + filename + " : " + link)
```

(not tested)

Note how we made the class a *context manager* by defining the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` magic methods.